# Why is passing this kind of variable-size parameter by value impossible?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, standards, parameter-passing

We have a structure like below:

```
template<size_t size>
class Container{
 public:
  char characters[size];
};
```

And we have a function like below:

```
template <size_t size>
void function(Container<size> input,size_t Size){
 //all instances do exactly same thing and with regard to Size that determines the size of object
}
```

Now in C++ for every value of size, a different instance of function will be created and apparently that's not right in this case since all instances do the same thing, to avoid this the first function parameter should be a pointer(char * pointer) instead of an object so that accepts any array with any size eliminating the need for function to be templated, but I'm curious having a single function which accepts a variable-size parameter like above that's not allowed by C++ is something impossible at all to implement and generate assembly for, or somehow leads to an inefficient implementation in terms of speed/memory ?

Comment: What is point of passing a `size` to your function ? `Container<size>` already has this information.

Comment: Any changes to OP, please put as EDIT 2 or something so that answers given before the edit don't start looking wrong.

Comment: What is worrying you so much about having multiple functions that do the same thing... so long as you only write ONE MODEL for all of them ? That is the goal of templates, you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, where you need an IN parameter, pass built-in types by value, and other types by reference to `const`, i.e.,

```
template< size_t size >
void function( Container<size> const& input,size_t Size )
{
 //all instances do exactly same thing and with regard to Size that determines the size of object
}
```

With this definition, chances are that the compiler+linker will optimize things so that there will be only one machine code version of `function`.

I was a bit surprised the first time I checked a simple small example program, that expressing it with compile time polymorphism (templating) produced smaller and more efficient code than expressing it with run time polymorphism!

Try it yourself, and if you're as surprised as I once was, then Good! Otherwise, chances are that there'll be no significant difference. But in some corner case you may find what in the old days was called "template code bloat", and then it's time to ignore it or measure whether it's significant enough to do work on translating to run time polymorphism.

Now to your question,

> "I'm curious having a single function
>   which accepts a variable-size
>   parameter like above that's not
>   allowed by C++ is something impossible
>   at all to implement and generate
>   assembly for, or somehow leads to an
>   inefficient implementation in terms of
>   speed/memory?"

No, it's not impossible to transform the compile time polymorphism to efficient run time polymorphism, or to simply *no polymorphism*. Especially since you're already passing a run-time size (which presumably is guaranteed smaller than the fixed size).

A safe way is to use `std::string` from the C++ standard library, header `<string>`. That involves dynamic allocation somewhere in the internals of `std::string`, done automatically for you, but affecting efficiency. But your code, containing `char[size] characters`, was not valid C++, and that indicates beginner level, so chances are that your design was not chosen for any good reason  --  hence, do:

```
class Container
{
public:
    std::string characters;
};

void function( Container const& input )
{
    // whatever, using e.g. input.characters.length()
}
```

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: @Alf P.Steinbach_"With this definition, chances are that the compiler+linker will optimize things so that there will be only one machine code version of function" I thought having one machine code version when there are different template arguments is impossible.

Comment: @Pooria: oh no, not impossible. a trivial case is when various instantiations of the template compiles directly to same machine code. all that's required is then for compiler+linker to recognize that.

Comment: @Alf P.Steinbach_So you mean because you used reference in your declaration you made having one machine code version possible or somehow pass by value may allow that too ?

Comment: @Pooria: "possible" is too strong here, because it would not be "impossible" with the original (corrected for syntax) code. But much more likely, yes. Because with the reference argument what's passed on the machine code level, assuming no inlining of the function, is in practice just the address of the actual arg. Cheers,

Comment: @Alf P.Steinbach_" possible is too strong here, because it would not be "impossible" with the original (corrected for syntax) code", by original you mean my function declaration or yours that has reference parameter?

Comment: @Pooria: by original I meant your function declaration, with pass by value. passing by value means different sizes of argument for different function template instantiations, hence possibly different machine code. the syntax I spoke of not in function but in `Container`. Cheers,

Comment: I believe that for normal calls in one TU, if you call a function template and the compiler sees all calls in a TU are direct and none goes over function pointers, the compiler can omit code creation of that function altogether or smelt them into one, because in any other TU, calling the function will in turn instantiate the function and will provide necessary code: The TUs don't depend on each other that way. That also means that a TU that calls a function template can't rely on definitions implicitly instantiated by other TUs - it can only rely on explicit instantiations of other TUs.

Comment: So I think @Alf as a good point here: The linker doesn't need to be smart because all work is done by the compiler and is granted by the C++ spec (see 14.8 in '03, which should be restored by http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1096 )

Answer (score 4):

It's common to delegate data that is independent of template arguments to a non-template base class, to avoid code duplication. In this case, the address of the first element of the array is not dependent on any template argument, so you can move it out

```
class ContainerBase {
 private: // can't be copied
  ContainerBase(ContainerBase const& o);
  ContainerBase &operator=(ContainerBase &);

 protected:
  ContainerBase(char *datap):datap(datap) { }

 public:
  char *data() { return datap; }

 private:
  char *datap;
};

template<std::size_t size>
class Container : public ContainerBase {
 public:
  Container():ContainerBase(d.characters)
  Container(Container const& o):ContainerBase(d.characters), d(o.d) 
  { }

  Container &operator=(Container const& o) {
    d = o.d;
    return *this;
  }

  struct {
   char characters[size];
  } d;
};


void function(ContainerBase const& input, std::size_t Size){
 /* operate on input.data() */
}
```

In a class small like that it probably wouldn't pay off, but cost/use ratio increases as the independent operations or the class itself grows. Note that if your goal is to have the class as aggregate then the above way is not feasible. You will need to either delegate work to some other non-templated function and live with the (possibly very small anyway) generated template specializations or you just pass the address of the array manually. This would also help making *non-template* functions more general

```
template<std::size_t size>
class Container : public ContainerBase {
 public:
  char *data() { return characters; }

 public:
  char characters[size];
};

// note that this function works in plain arrays too
void function(char *input, std::size_t Size){
 /* operate on input */
}

function(c.data(), N);
```

Incidentally, then you are at `boost::array<char, N>` which provides exactly that interface and other useful functions (still being an aggregate), although it's a bit too general in that it isn't fixed on `char`.

Comment: _Do you think that as Alf P.Steinbach has mentioned one version of machine code would be possible for different template arguments, if yes what those situations could be because I can't get myself to believe that.

Comment: @Pooria a sufficiently smart compiler/linker can do that for almost all uses of function templates. I *believe* that for normal calls in one TU, if you call a function template and the compiler sees all calls in a TU are direct and none goes over function pointers, the compiler can omit code creation of that function altogether, because in any other TU, calling the function will in turn instantiate the function and will provide necessary code: The TUs don't depend on each other that way.

Comment: Only when you explicitly compare function addresses, such optimizations are not possible anymore.

Comment: _So if I got it right one version of machine code may be possible for calls with different template arguments in one and only one TU and only if explicit function pointers to different versions aren't used because maybe by standard those different-type function pointers have to point to different versions of the function, am I right?

Comment: @Pooria, @Johannes: comparing function pointers does not prohibit single machine code function, but it's a quality of implementation issue (as is all this optimization stuff): if there's pointer comparison, then compiler+linker may have to generate multiple entry points for function. Here using the term "entry point" in the SESE/SEME meaning. It boils down to n jump instruction that jump to start of real function, for n logical instances of function. Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to have the size-templated function delegate the real work to an ordinary function that takes the size as an ordinary parameter:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdio>

template <size_t size>
struct Container
{
    char characters[size];
};

template <size_t size>
inline void function(const Container<size>& input)
{
    real_work(input.characters, size);
}

void real_work(const char* p, size_t len)
{
    while (len--) puts(p++);
}

int main()
{
    Container<6> x = {"hello"};
    function(x);
}
```

Note that I deliberately named the different kinds of arguments differently so you don't get confused.

Comment: @FredOverflow_Seriously, why is that "function" there when Container<size>.characters can be passed directly to real_work?

Comment: @Pooria: It makes the interface simpler for the user. If you never call `real_work` directly (it could be hidden from the user), you can never make the error of passing an incorrect value for `len`.

Answer (score 0):

Container<1> is a different *type* than Container<2>, and passing a pointer won't solve you anything, because they'll be pointer to different *types*.

Don't you think that **size** should be a Container's constructor parameter, not a templated value?

Comment: then it would work, but code such that would raise my eyebrows

Answer (score -1):

Its a poor design anyway. Passing arrays by value, or structs or classes for that matter, is extremely inefficient in both time and space anyway, as the entire array has to be copied into the target stack frame. Pass a reference.

Comment: which obviously mandates real arguments and performance measures... what if we need copy semantics ? what if we are talking about small arrays of a few chars ? what if even with twenty chars it's still near as fast ? what if we really don't care for performance here anyway ? Designs should not be subordinate of performance, as long as there's no performance issue anywyay

Comment: I agree about 'performance measures' but I take exception to 'real arguments'. You can't claim that what I wrote isn't a real argument. If you need copy semantics of course you must pay the price.

Answer (score -2):

Would something like this be acceptable for you:

```
class BaseContainer{ /* ... */ };

template<size_t size>
class Container : public BaseContainer{
 public:
  char[size] characters;
};

void function(BaseContainer input,size_t Size){
  //
}
```

Comment: That `char[size] characters` looks like a syntax error to me... ;-)

Comment: @Wimmel_How would you think it would be possible to write body of this function?!

Comment: char[size] is indeed a syntax error. I just copy-pasted the code from above. I just wanted to point to inheritance to solve this. And a pointer or reference would be better. @Pooria, I don't know exactly what you want.

Comment: @Wimmel_You can't make any use of "BaseContainer input" in that function because apart from "size_t Size" nothing is passed to this function at all !!!

Comment: Indeed, you should think it through. How is `function` going to access the `characters` members now?