# Is there the possibility of having one version of machine code for all template arguments of a templated function?

Tags: c++, templates, function, instantiation

Some people [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133307/here-different-instances-are-generated-for-this-template-function-or-not) told it's not possible and some people [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223603/why-is-passing-this-kind-of-variable-size-parameter-by-value-impossible) told it might be possible to have one version of machine code for all different template arguments of a templated function, so I thought it would be profitable to open a thread regarding this specific matter, if there is not such possibility that's it, if there is, in what situations can we count on this?
An example that was specifically considered in both mentioned threads is below:

```
template<size_t num>    
struct Elements{
 public:
  SomeType elements[num];
};

template<size_t num>
void print(const Elements<num> & elements,size_t size){
 //all instances do exactly same thing and with regard to Size that determines the size of object
}
```

and of course there's pass by value version also:

```
template<size_t num>
void print(const Elements<num> elements,size_t size){
 //all instances do exactly same thing and with regard to Size that determines the size of object
}
```

Comment: In your by-value example it's probably impossible to fold different instances together, because the size of the elements parameter would be different. That in turn would affect the function prolog/epilog (where the stack is allocated and then cleaned up).

Comment: @Crashworks_So the stack allocation can't does the job of reserving different sizes of stack frame per each function call?

Comment: You should try looking at a couple of function calls in your debugger's disassembly window and see how the stack is actually allocated. That would probably be more enlightening than anything I could fit into this little box. =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A smart linker can recognize when two different function bodies are identical and combine them together into one symbol. This is called "COMDAT folding" in MSVC and "duplicate stripping" most other places. For example, the following two functions might compile identically on PPC, although they take different types, because the types are the same size and behave identically in the given situation.

```
template<typename T>
GetLowBit( T foo ) { return T & 1; }

GetLowBit<unsigned long>(ulong x); // compiles to "li r4, 1 ; and r3, r3, r4 ; blr "
GetLowBit<signed long>(long x); // also compiles to "li r4, 1 ; and r3, r3, r4 ; blr "
```

and so the linker can make both of their "names" point to the same place, as it were, so that a call to `GetLowBit<unsigned long>` goes to the same address as a call to `GetLowBit<signed long>`. So, in general, it's possible to fold together different template instantiations of functions that all operate on identical type sizes in identical ways. (In particular, containers that store pointers or enums tend to get folded together.)

This doesn't just happen for template functions. Some linkers can notice when any two functions have identical bodies, and merge them. In particular I see that MSVC tends to collapse every virtual function that does nothing but return into one uber-function, eg for

```
class A
{ 
  virtual void nothing() {};
}

class B
{
   virtual void empty() {};
}
```

I often see (in the disassembler while debugging something else) that the vtable entries for `nothing` and `empty` both point to the same function body, which in turn is just a `ret`.

Can you count on this? No. This is a feature that a smart linker *might* provide for functions *when it notices them*. Your linker might be stupid — there's a lot of lousy compilers out there. It might only happen if you supply certain command arguments. It may happen for some functions but not others for reasons known only to the linker. It may even differ from build to build depending on what else is in the program.

So in general, yes this *can* happen, and when it does, it can be a nice savings in executable size. But you can't count on it happening unless you are very familiar with your linker and all its features.

Answer (score 0):

For most normal templates, this isn't possible. The entire reason that templates are used is because you need separate machine code for each of them. In your specific example, then the compiler is actually creating different types, which is most definitely not foldable, and in the take-by-value scenario (which is mad, by the way) it needs to know how much space the type will take up.

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding your specific query**:  If I need a template class where most functions are not differentiated by the template argument I usually make a non-template base class.  That allows me to move most of my methods off into a `.cc` file instead of a header and ensure that function copies don't proliferate unexpectedly.

**More generally**:  If you find yourself worried that you might make many specialized instances of your template due to a parameter (your `size_t num` is a fine example) you have probably discovered a template parameter that should really be a *constructor* parameter.

Comment: In this case it can't be a constructor parameter because it has to be a compile-time constant.

Comment: If you say that because of `SomeType elements[num]`, what's stopping you from going to `SomeType *elements` and dynamic allocation?  After all, `std::vector` manages to be very array-like without taking a size as a template parameter.